# Is it possible for me to have a method that can take both a HashMap or a list as an argument?

Tags: java, list, methods, parameters, hashmap

I have a function like the one listed below:

```
 private static void getNumberOfBrowsers(Collection<?> tcName){
 }
```

Is it possible for me to have a method that only takes one parameter, yet it can either be a `HashMap<String, String>` or `List<String>`?

Comment: What would you do with such a method? How would you treat the argument inside it?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? It would be better to have two methods, overloaded, and factor out common functionality into a single method that both call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *possible*, but it's **almost certainly a really bad idea**. The class those have in common is `Object`:

```
private static void getNumberOfBrowsers(Object tcName){
   // Need instanceof or similar here
}
```

Instead, consider an overloaded method:

```
private static void getNumberOfBrowsers(Map<String, String> tcName){
}

private static void getNumberOfBrowsers(List<String> tcName){
}
```

---

Side note: I used `Map<String>` above, not `HashMap<String>`. Generally, unless you have a good reason to require a specific type of something, it's best to code to the interface.

Comment: Awesome! I can go the overloaded method route, but why would it be a bad idea to use Object? I can do some validations with intanceOf to check if I'm getting what I'm supposed to correct?

Comment: @SahilGupta: If you used `Object`, I could call `getNumberOfBrowsers` with, say, a `Thread`. Or a `Date`. Or a `String`. Anything, really... So you'd have to throw a runtime exception for a compile-time bug. Really, better to catch those at compile-time.

Comment: You're right. I will go the overloaded method route. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **template class** as well. However it might be an overkill. Overloading will be simpler.

```
public class Box<T> {
   // T stands for "Type"
   private T t;

   public void set(T t) { this.t = t; }
   public T get() { return t; }
}
```

Example from : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: I didn't downvote, however I think you're right the template class might be an overkill. I will use method overloading. Thanks for the response!